# Compatibility in Spring version and Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am getting

> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [javax.servlet.FilterChain]: Specified class is an interface

when I use spring versions as  below. Any suggestions on the same

```
<spring.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
<spring.security.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.security.version>

My dispatcher servlet:
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Is this issue is happening because of spring compatibility version?